# How to identify through which access point I am connected?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, windows-10, wireless-access-point

I am roaming between several access points.

How do I know to which of them I am connected at any given moment?

Command line way is preferred.

Comment: `netsh wlan show all` will give you a list of bssids (macs) for each AP that are all broadcasting the same SSID. The strongest signal strength bssid is most likely the one you are connected to. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/chad/2011/08/02/tip-42-viewing-detailed-windows-7-wireless-information/

Comment: I don't need "most likely" information, I need precise information.